Flutter project implement CarPlay/Android Auto?
I am trying to find a sample or any project that implements CarPlay and Android Auto in a Flutter environment using native code, but I haven't found any so far. Any recommendations or links would be greatly appreciated.

Flutter doe not support Carplay/Android Auto diretly
There are some pacakges like CarPlay and Audo_Service but limited

Seen some comments and recommendation to implement using the native code, is there any example project?

CarPlay requires to use CarPlay templates . You can have some flexibility for map applications but user interaction is very limited as well as screen update.
